# Are these system specifications sufficient for upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10 from Windows 7 Starter?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, acer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which version and derivate of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware)

I was just concerned with Ubuntu 12.10 upgrading from my Acer Aspire one AOD270
Netbook.

- 320GB HDD
- 1GB DDR3 Memory
- 1.6Ghz Intel Atom N2600 Processor

With these system specifications, will the system work fine with Ubuntu (and much faster than Windows 7 Starter)?

I don't want to have a slow computer and I'm hoping this will be enough. Or will I have to go for Ubuntu 10.04?

I also want to make sure my Laptop won't have any BIOS errors or problems, so I'd like to know if there are any known problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep calm. Window 7 always consume more resources than Linux. If you want to be more secure you can install Kubuntu instead of Ubuntu that make the difference by using KDE that in my opinion consumes less graphic resources than the last interfaces of Ubuntu.

Also you have a big variety of Linus distributions, here you have a good list of the light-weight linux distros.

http://www.tuxradar.com/content/whats-best-lightweight-linux-distro

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Kubuntu is not a lightweight version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Of course not, but from my personal experience I had problems with Ubuntu graphics that were resolved by installing KDE. 
Gnome is faster than KDE because is more simple, but it's possible to have problems with the lasts versions if the computer is not too modern.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should work fine but not sure it will be faster than Windows 7 Starter.

Try a liveUSB with different flavours of Ubuntu before installing. The installed version will run faster than the live version though.

I would recommend Xubuntu and Lubuntu which are lighter than standard Ubuntu with Gnome/Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 will be fine on an Aspire One. My eMachines EM250 is very similar to your netbook and it worked fine with major no problems at all.